# React Material UI: error after importing some components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I try different Material UI components. Very very basic stuff.

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import injectTapEventPlugin from 'react-tap-event-plugin';

import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';

injectTapEventPlugin();

const App = () => (
<MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
        <FlatButton label="Default" />
        <FlatButton label="Primary" primary={true} />
        <FlatButton label="Secondary" secondary={true} />
        <FlatButton label="Disabled" disabled={true} />
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
);


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

It works without any problems. But if I add Menu component

```
///...///
import FlatButton from 'material-ui/FlatButton';
import Menu from 'material-ui/Menu';
import MenuItem from 'material-ui/MenuItem';

injectTapEventPlugin();
///...///
```

I see **Uncaught TypeError: wrapDisplayName is not a function** in the browser and everything is broken.

Comment: Paper and TimePicker components works fine. Stepper shows error

Comment: Do you use Menu tags somewhere or error happens just by adding import statement?

Comment: @yoK0 no, I do not use Menu somewhere else. All code in one file. I got error after just adding import statement. Also, I got this error if I import Stepper component.